# ASP_Merge resulting dll Default Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnet-compiler, aspnet-merge

I'm trying to merge all my aspx and ascx in a single dll with ASP_Merge.exe... it is working, and i did create the dll. My problem is, this merger creates a default namespace with the name "ASP" and inside are all the compiled ascx and aspx.

What i need is change this "ASP" namespace to "MyCustomNamespace". Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you **publish** the web application, it compiles your code into a `single DLL` anyway. See [How to publish a website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, i'm using the same commands publish use to build the dll i need... i need this dll to dinamically load the controls in another project. When i publish my webapp, it creates the dll with all the controls inside, but the namespace inside this dll is "ASP", i need to change this namespace and set it myself. Is there a way of doing this?